# LoadBalanced RestTemplate always get java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul

I am trying to set up client-side load balancing using ribbon and consul.

Spring boot version 2.1.4.Release
Spring cloud version Greenwich.SR1

From the log I can see that the service name got resolved correctly by query the consul agent, however, the request to the actual server always results in a SocketTimeoutException.

I have set the logging.level.org.apache.http to DEBUG. it seems the server actually respond successfully.

The relevant part of the log is attached.

```
2019-05-22 14:27:06.013  INFO 22692 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: mrqcon.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2019-05-22 14:27:07.492 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.492 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.492 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.492 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-Consul-Effective-Consistency: leader[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-Consul-Index: 779[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-Consul-Knownleader: true[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "X-Consul-Lastcontact: 0[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Wed, 22 May 2019 06:27:24 GMT[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 122[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xff][0xaa][0xe6]RPPPPJ[0xce][0xcf]+.[0xcd]Q[0xb2]R[0x88][0x8e][0xd5][0x81][0x88][0xe4][0x16][0x15]$[0x16][0x15][0xa7][0x16][0x81][0xc4][0xc0]"`[0xd1][0xe2][0xd4][0xe4][0xd2][0xa2]T[0xdb][0xb4][0xc4][0x9c][0xe2]T%[0x1d][0x84]xr~^IjEI@bI[0x86][0xad]~bA[0xa6]~[0x99][0xa1][0x9e][0x81]~jn[0x91][0x12]X[\r][0xc2][0xd0][0xc2][0xe4][0xfc]<T#qk[0xd5][0xc1]a/[0xc4]H[0xae]Z.@[0x0][0x0][0x0][0xff][0xff][0xa7][0xc2][0x1b][0x3][0xbd][0x0][0x0][0x0]"
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Content-Encoding: gzip
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Vary: Accept-Encoding
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-Consul-Effective-Consistency: leader
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-Consul-Index: 779
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-Consul-Knownleader: true
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << X-Consul-Lastcontact: 0
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Date: Wed, 22 May 2019 06:27:24 GMT
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 122
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:8500] can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
2019-05-22 14:27:07.493 DEBUG 22692 --- [TaskScheduler-1] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:8500][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 2 of 500; total allocated: 2 of 1000]
2019-05-22 14:27:08.394 DEBUG 22692 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-2 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
2019-05-22 14:27:08.394 DEBUG 22692 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-2: Close connection
2019-05-22 14:27:08.394 DEBUG 22692 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-2: Shutdown connection
2019-05-22 14:27:08.395 DEBUG 22692 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2019-05-22 14:27:08.395 DEBUG 22692 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 2][route: {}->http://30.5.40.181:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
2019-05-22 14:27:08.396  INFO 22692 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] c.a.m.n.h.m.utils.RemoteServiceHandler   : Retry request, execution count: 2, exception: {}

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingInputStream.read(LoggingInputStream.java:84) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) [httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) [httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) [httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) [httpclient-4.5.8.jar:4.5.8]
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.executeInternal(BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.java:63) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:108) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerRequestFactory.lambda$createRequest$0(LoadBalancerRequestFactory.java:61) [spring-cloud-commons-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:144) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:125) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:414) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.utils.RemoteServiceHandler.process(RemoteServiceHandler.java:130) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.core.MrParser.handleExternalCall(MrParser.java:636) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.core.MrParser.analyzeMrHelper(MrParser.java:589) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.core.MrParser.analyzeMrHelper(MrParser.java:604) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.core.MrParser.analyzeMrHelper(MrParser.java:584) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.core.MrParser.analyzeMrHelper(MrParser.java:604) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.core.MrParser.analyzeMr(MrParser.java:353) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.core.MrParser.analyzeMr(MrParser.java:374) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.alibaba.mit.nlp.haikou.mrparser.controller.ParseController.parse(ParseController.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]

2019-05-22 14:27:08.397  INFO 22692 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketTimeoutException) caught when processing request to {}->http://30.5.40.181:8080: Read timed out
2019-05-22 14:27:08.398 DEBUG 22692 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Read timed out
```

Comment: By `request to the actual server` you mean connection to `30.5.40.181:8080`? If so, make sure you are able to connect to `8080` port. Maybe firewall is blocking your connection, or just HTTP server running on some other port (maybe port `80`?).

Comment: Yes, I have double checked, 30.5.40.181:8080 can be successfully accessed, either using curl or using a normal(not with @loadbalanced) RestTemplate.

Comment: Also in the log, the apache httpclient indeed gets response from 30.5.40.181:8080, but somehow the Exception is still thrown